# How to create a date range from a list of dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a date range from a list of dates in Excel. I'd like to be able to take a column of many random dates and get a date range with the earliest and latest dates in the list. Something like this, with the formula creating the date range cells:

| Series | Date |
| --- | --- |
| ALPHA | 08/05/1999 |
| ALPHA | 11/13/2001 |
| ALPHA | 04/23/2003 |
| ALPHA | 07/01/1995 |
| ALPHA | 03/27/2000 |
| BRAVO | 05/03/2011 |
| BRAVO | 05/25/2008 |
| BRAVO | 08/18/2008 |
| BRAVO | 07/19/2011 |
| BRAVO | 01/05/2014 |
| BRAVO | 04/29/2017 |
| ALPHA date range | 07/01/1995 - 04/23/2003 |
| BRAVO date range | 05/25/2008 - 04/29/2017 |

Something like a SUMIF or COUNTIF formula to show the min/max of a series date range would be ideal, I'm not great with macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `TEXT`, `MINIFS`, and `MAXIFS`:

```
=TEXT(MINIFS(B1:B11,A1:A11,"ALPHA"),"mm/dd/yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(MAXIFS(B1:B11,A1:A11,"ALPHA"),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

[image]